# how to find the process that is doing io frequently?

Tags: linux, io, command

I am using ubuntu. There are some processes that are doing io frequently on my server, even a "ls" command will cost 1 second to execute. I want to find out which process is doing io so heavily, is there any good command or tool?

Thanks.

Comment: To accept answers, click the check mark next to your preferred answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the process which is cosuming the most i/o in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466496/how-to-find-the-process-which-is-cosuming-the-most-i-o-in-linux)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `iotop` to find processes that are io heavy.

Comment: Don't forget to run iotop with **sudo** or it wil fail.

Answer (score 10):

A quick way is to look at the `/proc/[PID]/io` file.

Example:

```
$ cat /proc/1944/io
read_bytes: 17961091072
write_bytes: 8192000
cancelled_write_bytes: 32768
```

Comment: you have written about the best method :) It is usable for writting script for controlling process. when process consumes too much io, it can be stopped by sigstop, and after io go down, it should be waked up by sigcont :)

Answer (score 6):

[iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) has a top-like interface and shows how much I/O reads and writes each process is doing.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/) which can report disk reads and writes by processes among many other things.

[image: Disk utilization — key 'd']

Answer (score 3):

you can try pidstat.
I found it useful when i need to identify which process made high io.